# How to fix Code not displaying anaconda prompt as Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

The Python interpreter is working fine and is fully configured. So it should be using the anaconda prompt by default for the Terminal. However this has not been the case so I tried setting up manually. This is what I've set so far:
[image: Fig_1]

This is the prompt when I hover over 'terminal.inegrated.defaultProfile.windowss" value:
[image: Fig_2]

Also 'Anaconda Shell' is not selectable from the dropdown for the Terminal sub-window. It doesn't show there but the rest are being displayed:

[image: Fig_3]

Is there a away to actually override Code to recognise the anaconda prompt to be set as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure it like this:

```
"Anaconda": {
  "path": "cmd.exe",
  "args": ["/K", "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"]
}
```